# How to create a sql script to migrate multicolumn data into a single column as json

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Database : mysql 5.6**

Earlier i had a table with columns:

```
     1) id (int)
     2) name (varchar)
     3) returnEnabled (boolean)
     4) return type (varchar)
     5) immediateReturn (varchar)
```

Now we had a table with columns 1,2, and a column named actions which contains values of column 3,4,5 as json string.

Can anyone please suggest how to migrate data to new table schema using sql script do that ?

Earlier table was like :

[image]

Now table is like :

[image]

Comment: could you post sample data and expected out put.

Comment: @Praveen : added the earlier and new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    name,
    created,
    updated
    CONCAT (
        '{"returnEnabled":', 
        IF(returnEnabled = 0, 'false', 'true'), 
        ',"immediateRpi":',
        IF(immediateReturn = '0', 'false', 'true'),
        ',"ReturnType":"',return_type,'"}'
    ) as actions
from old_table;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT` function to build your JSON, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('{', 
           '"returnANabled":', IF(return_enabled = 0, 'false', 'true'),
         '}') AS actions
FROM EarlierTable
```